# What is the Rspec 3.0 matcher for =~?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

Say you have:

```
Article.keys.should =~ [:title, :year, :title_length]
```

Which becomes in Rspec 3.0

```
expect(Article.keys).to =~ [:title, :year, :title_length]
```

Except that it fails with:

```
ArgumentError:
   The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to `#to`.
```

**Key Question**: What is the matcher in Rspec 3.0 for the `=~` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to match_array([2, 1, 3])
```

I think that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Worth to mention from the [`Rspec 3.0 Collection membership`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers#collection_membership)

```
expect(array).to match_array(expected_array)
# ...which is the same as:
expect(array).to contain_exactly(individual elements)
```

Examples from doc :-

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to contain_exactly(2, 1, 3)
# is exactly same as below
expect([1, 2, 3]).to match_array([3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: Using an include matcher like that would not cause the spec to fail if there were extra items in the array

Comment: @FrederickCheung I forgot to remove that.. Thanks for the pointer.. While I was updating it with my second update, I planned to remove that, but I forgot that.